# Calculate the Average for the last x records belonging to a distinct groupset

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the average of time for each part_id for the last 2 batches where the part_id is found and the average of time for each part_id for all the batches.

I have managed to isolate the Average of a part_id for the last 2 batches it was found but I can't integrated into the code so that it does the calculation for each part ID.  I get an error Unknown column 'tst.part_id' in 'where clause', I need to pass that tst.part_id value to my nested select query.

Below is a fiddle I have:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77bea5/85

Query I am using:

```
SELECT tst.part_id,
  AVG(tst.est_time) AS 'Average Time Overall',

(SELECT AVG(ft.avgLastMax)
FROM 
(SELECT t2.avglst as 'avgLastMax', t2.numval as 'numval'
 FROM (SELECT 
      @num:=CASE WHEN @last != tst3.batch_id
      THEN @num:=(@num + 1)
      ELSE @num:=@num END 'numval',
      @last:=tst3.batch_id,
       @name:=CASE WHEN @num > 2 
        THEN @name:=@name
        ELSE @name:=(tst3.est_time) END 'avglst'
      FROM test AS tst3,
      ( select @last:=0, @avg := 0, @name :=0 , @num :=0) var
       /* GET AVERAGE FOR A SINGLE PART ID
       WHERE tst3.part_id = 1 */ 
        WHERE tst3.part_id = tst.part_id
      ORDER BY tst3.run_id DESC) as t2

  )
 as ft
WHERE ft.numval <3) as 'AVG on last 2 batches'

FROM test AS tst
GROUP BY tst.part_id;
```

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
part_id   AVG on last 2 batches    Average Time Overall

1         27.25                    25.67

2         22.5                     22.5

3         16.67                    16.67

4         47.5                     47.5
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`part_id` int, `est_time` int, `batch_id` int, `run_id` int, `line` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO test
    (`part_id`, `est_time`, `batch_id`, `run_id`, `line`)
VALUES
    (1, 20, 1, 1, 'T'),
    (1, 25, 1, 2, 'T'),
    (2, 30, 1, 3, 'T'),
    (3, 15, 1, 4, 'T'),
    (1, 10, 2, 5, 'X'),
    (4, 40, 2, 8, 'X'),
    (2, 15, 3, 9, 'T'),
    (3, 15, 3, 10, 'T'),
    (3, 20, 3, 11, 'T'),
    (1, 34, 4, 12, 'X'),
    (1, 32, 4, 13, 'X'),
    (1, 33, 4, 14, 'X'),
    (4, 55, 5, 15, 'T')
;
```

EDITED: Corrected the table and order by tst3.run_id DESC to get the last batch_id.

Comment: The numbers in your expected output don't seem to add up.  For instance, `part_id` 1 seems to have an average of `32.5` over the two most recent batches.

Comment: I inverted the order by mistake, it should be 27.25 for part_id 1, ((33 + 32 + 34 + 10) / 4)

Comment: (part_id,batch_id,run_id) is UNIQUE/PRIMARY, right?

Comment: @Strawberry run_id is AI and UQ

Comment: @Strawberry no, there can be duplicate part_id in a batch_id, the run_id is the pk

Comment: Can you provide the data set upon which the 'last 2' calculation should be averaged?

Comment: @Strawberry for the part_id #1, the average will be calculated based on the est_time of that part_id found on batch_id #4 and #2. The est_time of part_id #1 found in batch_id #1 cannot be included because that is fhe 3rd batch_id found (it is not part of the last 2 batches where a part id is found). This should be true for all part_id's.  For part_id #1 only the run_id 5, 12, 13 and 14 should be used in the last 2 calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first result is wrong...

```
SELECT a.part_id
     , AVG(a.est_time) 
  FROM test a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.part_id
            , x.batch_id 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT part_id 
                            , batch_id 
                         FROM test
            ) x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT part_id
                            , batch_id 
                         FROM test
            ) y 
           ON y.part_id = x.part_id 
          AND y.batch_id >= x.batch_id 
        GROUP
           BY x.part_id
            , x.batch_id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
     ) b 
    ON b.part_id = a.part_id 
   AND b.batch_id = a.batch_id 
 GROUP 
    BY a.part_id;
+---------+-----------------+
| part_id | AVG(a.est_time) |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 |         27.2500 |
|       2 |         22.5000 |
|       3 |         16.6667 |
|       4 |         47.5000 |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Or, faster... with variables...

```
SELECT part_id
     , AVG(est_time) last_2_avg
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @part_id = part_id 
                   THEN CASE WHEN @batch_id = batch_id THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END
                   ELSE @i:=1
                   END i
            , @part_id := part_id
            , @batch_id:= batch_id
         FROM test x
            , (SELECT @part_id := null, @batch_id:=null, @i:=1) vars
        ORDER
           BY part_id
            , batch_id DESC
     ) a
 WHERE a.i <= 2
 GROUP 
    BY part_id;

+---------+------------+
| part_id | last_2_avg |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |    27.2500 |
|       2 |    22.5000 |
|       3 |    16.6667 |
|       4 |    47.5000 |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Your calculation for the last 2 is correct and alot cleaner than my code. I will have to inner join this results woth the average time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT W.*,T1.ALLAVG
FROM (
SELECT V.PART_ID, AVG(V.EST_TIME) LAST2 FROM
(
SELECT U.PART_ID,U.MAXRN,X.RUN_ID,X.EST_TIME
FROM
(
/*LAST 2*/
SELECT S.PART_ID,MAX(S.RN) MAXRN
FROM
(
/*DERIVE A ROW NUMBER*/
SELECT T.PART_ID , T.RUN_ID,
         IF (CONCAT(T.PART_ID,T.RUN_ID)  <> @R ,@RN:=@RN+1,@RN:=1) RN,
         @R:=CONCAT(T.PART_ID,T.RUN_ID) R
FROM     (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0,@R:=0) RN, TEST T
ORDER   BY T.PART_ID,T.RUN_ID
) S
GROUP   BY S.PART_ID
) U

/*USING THE MAX ABOVE GET THE LAST 2 */
JOIN 

(SELECT T.PART_ID , T.RUN_ID,T.EST_TIME,
         IF (CONCAT(T.PART_ID,T.RUN_ID)  <> @R1 ,@RN1:=@RN1+1,@RN1:=1) RN,
          @R1:=CONCAT(T.PART_ID,T.RUN_ID) R
FROM     (SELECT @RN1:=0,@P1:=0,@R1:=0) RN, TEST T
ORDER   BY T.PART_ID,T.RUN_ID

) X ON X.PART_ID = U.PART_ID AND (X.RN BETWEEN U.MAXRN -1 AND U.MAXRN) #AMEND THIS FOR THE LAST N REQUIRED
) V
GROUP BY V.PART_ID
) W
JOIN
/*ALL*/
(SELECT T.PART_ID,AVG(T.EST_TIME) 'ALLAVG' FROM TEST T GROUP BY T.PART_ID) T1 ON T1.PART_ID = W.PART_ID
```

RESULT

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| PART_ID | LAST2   | ALLAVG  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 | 32.5000 | 25.6667 |
|       2 | 22.5000 | 22.5000 |
|       3 | 17.5000 | 16.6667 |
|       4 | 47.5000 | 47.5000 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```